# Bootstrap popover on list data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootstrapping

I have a list of elements with fields like 'Category', 'Name' and 'Value' that I bind inside a table:

```
<table class="table" data-bind="visible: document.pvm.tehnicalTab().length > 0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Category</td>
         <td>Name[86, 0]</td>
         <td>Value[439, 0]</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: elemList()">
      <tr>
         <td data-bind="text: $data.Category"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: $data.Value"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

I'm trying to add a popover for each Value field that will display a message with a random number.

I added:

```
 <div data-bind='component: "tehnical-val"'></div>
```

inside the Value field :

```
<td data-bind="text: $data.Value">
   <div data-bind='component: "tehnical-val"'></div>
</td>
```

and the javascript for it:

```
    ko.components.register('tehnical-val', {
template: '<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-placement="right" container="body" tabindex="0" data-contentwrapper=".cartContent" data-original-title="" title="">' +
    'VID=7' + '</a>'
        });
```

But when I click one of the labels with a value from the list nothing happen.
Is there a way to add a popover on a list data-bind fields?

Comment: The `text` binding will obliterate your inner `<div>`. You may want to put the text binding on a `span` inside the `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that invokes the `$().popover()` function on the elements.  e.g.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapPopover = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $el = $(element);
    $el.attr('data-toggle', 'popover');
    $el.attr('data-trigger', 'hover');
    $el.attr('data-html', 'true');
    $el.attr('data-placement', 'left');
    $el.attr('data-content', ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    $el.popover();
  } 
};
```

Then add the binding to the element, e.g.

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.value, bootstrapPopover: $data.popoverContent"></div>
```

I've created a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/nae5uzo7/) with the binding. Note that this is a very basic binding. It calls $().popover() for every element and it doesn't update the popover content dynamically.  So there is room for improvement.

[image]

Comment: I've tried your fiddle but it doesn't work for me. In the table you've added 3 elements but I can see only the first one and also no popover :(

Comment: I've tested the fiddle in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on OS X and attached a screen shot of it working.  Check the console and see if there are any errors in the log.